# Is "swallow spittle" an acceptable phrase?

Tags: phrases

I came across the following sentence in Ken Liu's Translation of *The Three-Body Problem*:

> Her throat hurt so much that swallowing spittle felt like it was a piece of burning coal.

The original text is as follows:

> “咽下一口唾沫感觉像咽下一块火炭”

Google's definition of *spittle* says:

> saliva, especially as ejected from the mouth.

It seems like an odd combination of words. But, on further research it seems like there is some history to this coupling. *[The Eastern Mirror: An Illustration of the Sacred Scriptures; In Which the Customs of Oriental Nations Are Clearly Developed by the Writings of the Most Celebrated Travellers](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=F1MOAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=%22swallow%20spittle%22&source=bl&ots=ETb0VjA-sx&sig=kjA-RIGARlY7nQjVHZ6kom7XzT4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmtMOKoPvdAhVac3AKHdOTCO8Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22swallow%20spittle%22&f=false)*, for instance, contains the following proverb:

> NO. 203 —— TO SWALLOW SPITTLE, A PROVERB.
>   vii. 19. *Let me alone 'till I swallow down my spittle.*
>   This is a proverb among the Arabians to the present day; by which they understand give me leave.

Perhaps, it has a bit of a Biblical ring to it. Is it an acceptable phrase?

Comment: Well, it's something we all do constantly without thinking about it (until we have a sore throat). 'Spittle' is a rather old-fashioned term for saliva. 'Avaler sa salive' is a normal expression in French for what you might do when startled or embarrassed; in English we would just say 'swallow' or 'gulp'.

Comment: @KateBunting I guess my grievance was with the: **especially as ejected from the mouth** part. Sounds more like you'd be swallowing someone else's saliva rather than your own. Which is getting iffy.

Comment: _How long wilt Thou not depart from me, nor let me alone till I swallow down my spittle ? I have sinned._ [Job 7:19](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/18007019) Authorised King James translation.

Comment: It is fine. It is colorful. "Saliva" would have worked as well. The word "spittle" might be considered unnecessary.

Comment: It's a literal statement formed from the combination of individual words. Although, people currently refer to *spit* more often than *spittle*.